# Flask and Heroku: Key Error while getting session variable

Tags: python, html, flask, heroku

So I'm trying to set up a basic site in Heroku that runs perfectly locally. I have this following code on user log-in that executes fine:

```
@app.route("/callback")
def callback():
    token = oauth.authorize_access_token()
    session["userinfo"] = oauth.parse_id_token(token)
    name = session['userinfo']['name']
    email = session['userinfo']['email']
```

But then when I attempt to use the session variables in a different def, I receive the log error 'KeyError: 'userinfo'' here:

```
@app.route("/profile", methods=["GET", "POST"])
def profile():
    if request.data:
        results = request.json
        con = db_connect()
        c = con.cursor()
        c.execute("select hash from users where email = %s", (session['userinfo']['email'],))
```

I already printed the name in callback in the console to verify that the Auth0 portion is working, but I'm guessing that Heroku isn't handling the session variables well for some reason?

Comment: did you solve it ?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using config variables in Heroku, check to make sure they do not have any hyphens. It's mentioned in Heroku's documentation. I had an app that was running perfectly fine locally, but also got a KeyError when it was run on Heroku. Turns out my config variables keys had hyphens and after changing them to underscores, error was gone!